# Atualizar registro com Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.2

Tenho a seguinte função :

```
public function alterar($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::find($id);
    $params = $request->all();
    $produto->fill($params)->save();
    return redirect()->action('ProdutoController@index');
}
```

porém toda vez que eu altero um produto, um novo dele é adicionado no banco (uma nova cópia atualizada) e o antigo continua lá, então o que está acontecendo é uma cópia e não efetivamente a atualização daquele produto?

Comment: O id que você está recebendo está correto com o buscado no banco? Tente utilizar `findOrFail` ao invés de `find` para ver se estoura algum erro

Comment: Verfica se o banco de dados não tem alguma trigger fazendo insert  porque não vejo erro no seu código.

Comment: Em vez de usar `find`, use `findWhere`, talvez seja a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia verificar se o item realmente foi setado e se o mesmo existe com a propriedade publica [$exists](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L90):

```
public function alterar($id)
{
    $produto = Produto::find($id);
    if ($produto && $produto->exists)
    {
        $params = $request->all();
        $produto->fill($params)->save();
    }
    return redirect()->action('ProdutoController@index');
}
```

*A sua dúvida me parece tanto quanto estranha também, talvez uma averiguação maior na rotas e nos `Controller` para ver se tem algum código chamando errado seria uma boa ideia do que possa estar acontecendo.*

***Referencia:*** [public $exists = false;](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L90)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update($id)
{
    $produto= Produto::find($id);
    $produto->update(Input::all());
    return view('suaView');
}
```

Lembrando de ter os campos $fillable cadastrados no model para o Mass Assignment funcionar direito e de forma segura.

Também deve adicionar a rota adequada, por exemplo:

```
Route::post('produto/{id}', 'ProdutosController@update');
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   $produto = Produto::findOrFail($id);
   $produto->update($request->all());
   return view('view');
 }
```